# Sample size for survival analysis - why estimate probability of failure for control and intervention arm

Tags: r, survival, sample-size

I was using R's "[powerSurvEpi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/powerSurvEpi/powerSurvEpi.pdf)" package to perform sample size calculations for a clinical trial where I expect a protective effect of the intervention. I used the ssizeCT.default function because I don't have a pilot dataset.

`ssizeCT.default(power = 0.8, k, pE, pC, RR, alpha = 0.05)`

k = ratio of participants in group E (experimental group) compared to group C (control group)

pE = probability of failure in group E (experimental group) over the maximum time period of the study (t years).

pC = probability of failure in group C (control group) over the maximum time period of the study (t years).

RR = postulated hazard ratio.

Can somebody explain me why I have to estimate the probability of failure for **both** the control and intervention group **AND** the HR. Shouldn't the probability of failure in the intervention group depend on the estimated probability of failure in the control group and the HR? Why do I have to estimate this as well?

Thanks in advance for your explanation.